# Cosa significa "posta" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella prefazione a *Nostro lunedí* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Ma in Croazia, a Credévick e a Musrak, il caso volle che fossi io di scena. Naturalmente ero l’uomo meno adatto per questo: tutt’al piú, io ero uno di quei talenti irrequieti eternamente alla **posta** del bello, e mai disposti, però, a fare un mezzo passo per muoversi in cerca. Mi piaceva molto guardare, ecco tutto: avevo il discutibile dono d’una fantasia superiore alla media che mi permetteva di verniciare di fresco anche gli aspetti piú degradanti o piú miseri, e un’ironia un poco ignobile per riderci o sorriderci su e una meridionale pigrizia che m’impediva di conoscere fino in fondo la noia: in fondo saper apprezzare piú l’interessante che il bello, con tutte le sue originalità rasentava, in complesso, il banale.

Ho cercato il termine "posta" in parecchi dizionari ma, tra le tantissime accezioni che appaiono,  non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qui utilizzato secondo me nel senso di *"Fare la posta a"* ovvero *"Appostarsi"* (vedi http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/posta def. 5 oppure http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appostare1/)

La cosa viene chiarita nel seguito della frase, in cui chi parla chiarisce che la sua ricerca *"del bello"* non è attiva (non muove *"mezzo passo"*), ma passiva.